# How to prevent selected fields from being updated in Y.js?

Tags: javascript, crdt

Imagine object like this

```
const project = { 
  editors:{'me@stack.com':'owner', 'they@stack.com':'manager' },
  title:'myStackProject',
  article:'I love to ask questions'
}
```

In my case managers can't edit title and rights but they can edit article. So the problem is how to prevent project.title, users and their rights from being modify made by managers.
I use Y.js & y-socket.io
Maybe you have already met the problem and know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to store the fields in separate `Y.Doc`s - one for editors & title, one for article.

If you have a server with access to the doc, in principle it could validate updates before accepting them: apply the update to a copy of the doc, inspect the `Y.Event` to see what changed, and reject if the user doesn't have permission. This can get complicated though.